# In Haskell, I want to make simple concordancer. But it response errors again, and again

Tags: haskell

```
import System.IO
import Data.List
import Data.Char
printlist :: Show a => a -> IO ()
printlist x = putStr (show x)
main = do
     handle <- openFile "/usr/local/share/corpus" ReadMode
     text <- hGetContents handle
     let wlist = words text
         clist = map (\k -> take ((k + 15) - k + 1).drop (k - 10))(elemIndices "word" wlist)
printlist clist
```

What can I do to finish my job.
please, give me a answer or hints

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: `\k -> take ((k + 15) - k + 1) . drop (k-10)` --- what this function is for?

Comment: Additionally, did you realize that `take ((k + 15) - k + 1)` is just `take 16`?  And this wouldn't compile because `clist` is a list of functions and therefore `printList` won't work on it, since `(a -> b)` has no instance for `Show`.  @jozefg I see `printlist` right between `import Data.Char` and `main`.

Comment: @bheklilr Drat you're right... I need coffee before I try to answer SO questions

Answer (score 3):

Well I felt nice, so I fixed up the errors here

```
import Data.List

printlist :: Show a => a -> IO ()
printlist = putStr . show

main = do
     text <- readFile "/usr/local/share/corpus" -- removed useless handle
     let clist = zipWith (flip ($)) (repeat text)
                -- ^ applied each function to file
                -- since you currently had
                -- clist :: [String -> String]
                 . map (\k -> take 16 . drop (k-10))
                 . elemIndices "word"
                 $ words text -- inlined wlist
     printlist clist -- fixed indenting
```

So now what this does is produce a list of functions of type `String -> String` and apply each of them to the file `/usr/local/share/corpus` and print the result.

I suppose the map part can be rewritten to be

```
(.:) = (.) . (.)
infixr 9 .:

map (take 16 .: drop . subtract 10)
```

Which is arguably prettier.

Comment: Since `subtract = flip (-)` and is only there for right operator sections, we have `flip subtract ≡ (-)`, so you can even have `map (take 16 .: drop . (10 -))`.